# Splitting String using first entry

Tags: scala

Say I have a list:

```
val l = List("and", "or", "up to").
```

I want to check if anyone of these entries from `l` are present in a string. If it is present, then the string will be split using the first found entry from `l`. If not, then the entire string is returned.

So for example, let's say our string is: `"1.5 litres of milk or 2 apples"` should return `List("1.5 litres of milk", "2 apples")`.

On the other hand a string like `"1.5 litres of milk along with 2 apples"` should return `List("1.5 litres of milk along with 2 apples")`.

Comment: I tried the below one, but it yields full string if first match is not there but second one is there :val entry = 
      for {split <- splitd} yield caseLine.split(split) 
      
    entry.toList.flatten.distinct
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming (from your comment) that "caseLine" contains the text to be split, you can try:

```
l.find(caseLine.contains).map(caseLine.split)
                         .map(_.toList.map(_.trim))
                         .getOrElse(caseLine :: Nil)
```

Find returns the first element of `l` found in `caseLine`, as an `Option`, which is then mapped to produce `caseLine` split, then trimmed, and finally the `getOrElse` returns the original `caseLine` if `find` returned `None`. The results have all been converted to `List[String]` for consistent typing of the results.

Comment: Thanks a lot Shadowlands. It worked perfectly fine :)

Comment: Shadowlands, what shall I do if I want to split "caseLine" string with all those entries present in "l" which are there in "caseLine" instead of just the first one found.

Comment: @ Shadowland in continuation to previous question, let's say: val l = List("and", "or", "up to")        and              val caseLine = "Increment of 50 mg weekly or 80 mg every 2 weeks, up to a total of 200 mg each week"      should result in Output    val entry = List("Increment of 50 mg weekly", "80 mg every 2 weeks,", "a total of 200 mg each week")   Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Chaks That can be done with a fold over `l`, starting with `caseLine` as the only entry in an array, then successively splitting each element of the array around each element of `l`, using flatMap to ensure you have just one dimension in the array after processing each element of `l`: `l.foldLeft(Array(caseLine))( (a, l) => a.flatMap(_.split(l)) )`. Look at the documentation for `foldLeft` and `flatMap` to learn more.

Comment: Thanks again @Shadowland and also for suggesting to study a bit about foldLeft and flatMap. Will surely do the same, still a toddler as far as scala is concerned :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def splitOnFirstMatch(splitters: List[String], s: String): List[String] = {
    splitters.find(s.contains) match {
        case Some(x) => s.split(x).map(_.trim).toList
        case None => List(s)
    }
}
```

I am first finding the first string in `splitters` that are contained in `s`, then I return the string splitted on this word. I return the list with the input string if no splitter exists.

Comment: Thanks a lot marstran. It's working exactly how I wanted :)